# Can't create a new HomeGroup in Windows 8

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8

I'm trying to create a new HomeGroup in Windows 8 for 2 new PCs with Windows 8 installed so that I can share printers etc.  Both PCs use Microsoft Account to log in - a Microsoft Account I set up about a year ago with one of the early beta's with a PC that's since been repaved with the RTM of Windows 8

When I click on "HomeGroup" in the "Metro" control panel the "Create" option is not there. Instead I'm told that "HomeGroup" already exists on the PC I've since repaved and renamed and I can join it by entering the password.

I have no recollection of what the password might have been and in any event that PC doesn't exist, but there is no way to say "That group doesn't exist anymore just create me a new one dammit".

Even using the old Control Panel the "HomeGroup" nonsense persists with the only option being "Join" that needs a password.

How do I "start afresh" and create a new HomeGroup that I can use to connect my Windows 8 and Windows 7 PCs and use common printers, network drives etc.

Comment: Which edition of Windows 8 is on the PCs?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing all Homegroups from both computers first?

I've reinstalled a few machines and almost every time there are issues. I tend to find taking all machines out of their homegroup and recreating from scratch works.